# svn tree conflict

Tags: svn

I keep getting tree conflicts and I can''t seem to understand the reason even reading all the threads. My background is in clearcase so svn is new to me. The tree conflict does not make sense when I relate it to any clearcase activity. Below is my situation that causes the issue.

I have the standard svn structure of trunk, branches, and tags areas.
The trunk is our production code, developers do not work here.

The situation is this developer a creates a directory called fix1 in the branches area and copies the file to work on in this area from the trunk. When the work is done the release groups merges the change back to the trunk. This works fine

Next developer takes creates a directory under branches called fix2 and takes a copy of the file from trunk (that was just merged back in the previous example by rm) when his changes are done this is merged back to trunk and we get a tree conflict.

In all cases the developer did an svn up in his work area and the rm person did a svn up before the merge back

In both cases the the rm person changed directory to trunk and did a svn merge ../branches/fix1 or svn merge ../branches/fix2

The question is three fold

what is causing the tree conflict?

when I resolve the conflict (svn resolve -R --accept=working ) I then do not get the contents of the file merged back?

What is the recommended approach for this type of work?

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Thanks

Comment: Silly question, but I'm assuming that the trunk was committed after doing a svn merge?

Answer (score 2):

The problem probably comes from the way you create branches:

> this developer a creates a directory called fix1 in the branches area and copies the file to work on in this area from the trunk.

That's not what should be done. You shouldn't copy files manually. Instead, you should create a branch from the trunk, switch your working copy to this branch, make modifications and commits. At regular intervals, and when the work on the branch is finished, you should merge from trunk to branch, to incorporate all the changes from trunk into branch.

Then you should switch to the trunk, reintegrate the branch into the trunk, commit, and delete the branch.

This is explained in [the SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.feature) in more details.

Comment: so are you saying cd to the branches directory and d svn mkdir fix1 then switch to this area and then do the work? do not use copy, that was information supplied to me. Can you provide me with an example and a link to some documentation on this?  Thanks

Comment: No. That's not how to create a branch. A branch is created using `svn copy`. I already linked to the SVN book in my answer, but here's another link: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge

Comment: Maybe I'm mis-stating something. Teh svn copy of trunk to branch assumes I believe A full copy of the trunk (all files) I may want just one file that is why I did the svn copy of a specific file from trunk to branch then did my work in the branch direcory n the one file

Comment: SVN copies are cheap copies. They're just a pointer to an existing tree. Read... the SVN book: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.using.create. You should always branch from the root of the project. You are missing key concepts of SVN, and all these concepts are extremely well explained in the  free SVN book. Why don't you read it?

Comment: I'm going to but I just saw it. It functions much different than what I'm use to with clearcase.